# pressing home button and go again in activity restat the first activity not the last

Tags: android, android-activity, minimize

when I press home button from my application during second activity, and switch back to my application, it restart with the first activity and not resume the last one.

any idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.vulneraria.cento"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fiorenero"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="it.vulneraria.cento.Cento"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="it.vulneraria.cento.CentoGame"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

this is manifest, you need the code of activity? i use only the default for onPause onResume ect...

Comment: add some code. Do you manipulate the activity task with some attributes like ` android:clearTaskOnLaunch` ?

Comment: Are you using some flag in the Intent? Maybe you can add that code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) is the piece of documentation you are asking for. The resources on [Android's Developer Page](http://developer.android.com) are great- they will introduce you to the concepts and the APIs alike.